# Why does java.text.DateFormat return the same date format for en_US and en_GB on Android?

Tags: java, android, locale, date-format

I have a small Android application which I'm using to print a specific date in different formats based on locale.

Here is my code (using `java.text.DateFormat`):

```
Locale[] locales = {new Locale("en", "US"), new Locale("en", "GB"), new Locale("en", "AU"), new Locale("en", "NZ"), new Locale("en", "ZA")};
for(int i = 0; i < locales.length; ++i) {
    Log.d(logKey, locales[i].toString() + " - " + DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locales[i]).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
}
```

The output from this in LogCat is thus:

```
D/FormatPoC(  390): en_US - 4/27/12
D/FormatPoC(  390): en_GB - 4/27/12
D/FormatPoC(  390): en_AU - 4/27/12
D/FormatPoC(  390): en_NZ - 4/27/12
D/FormatPoC(  390): en_ZA - 4/27/12
```

So my question is - why are all of these the same? In Java SE I get:

```
en_US - 4/27/12
en_GB - 27/04/12
en_AU - 27/04/12
en_NZ - 27/04/12
en_ZA - 2012/04/27
```

Which is what I would expect. I know that I can use `android.text.format.DateFormat` to get correct results based on the user's current locale and date order setting, but that doesn't explain why using `java.text.DateFormat` to get the format for a programmatically specified locale doesn't return the right results.

Additionally, it's not just the `SHORT` date format - `MEDIUM` and `LONG` show inconsistencies between Android and Java SE as well (i.e. Android returns the same format for all 5 Locales I specified).

I've tested it on 3 different devices (2.3 and 4.0) and on the emulator (2.3 and 4.0), all with the same results. I've also tested using `Locale.US` and `Locale.UK` just to see if they're somehow different, but the results are the same.

Has anyone else run into this, or know why this would be?

**UPDATE: 2012-07-18**

It appears that this is an issue with the emulator, as well as many devices manufactured in the US. Using Dalvik Explorer:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jessies.dalvikexplorer&hl=en

I've been able to see what the system returns for en_GB on different devices (including the emulator). Some return the appropriate formats, some return the en_US format. I assume this is simply an issue of what format resources are built into the OS for each device, though being that the *emulator* returns the wrong formats as well as many of my US-manufactured devices, I wonder what British developers think, or if they've seen this problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer (I do not yet have enough rep to add a comment...)

As a UK developer I have come across this problem. I am seeing this problem with my Galaxy S3, exactly as you have described.

I'm having to resort to allowing the user to choose the date format as a preference. Not very good.

The DalvikExplorer program also shows the problem:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! It's such an odd issue, because I've seen other devices that return the appropriate formatting for en_GB.

Comment: Yes indeed. I have also tried with an HTC Desire and that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    int style = DateFormat.MEDIUM;
    //Also try with style = DateFormat.FULL and DateFormat.SHORT
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat df;
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.UK);
    Log.d("Locale.UK","Locale.UK - "+df.format(date));
    System.out.println("United Kingdom: " + df.format(date));
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.US);
    Log.d("Locale.US","Locale.US - "+df.format(date));
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.FRANCE);
    Log.d("Locale.FRANCE","Locale.FRANCE - "+df.format(date));
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.ITALY);
    Log.d("Locale.ITALY","Locale.ITALY - "+df.format(date));
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.JAPAN);
    Log.d("Locale.JAPAN","Locale.JAPAN - "+df.format(date));
```

Comment: Though that's pretty much exactly what I'm doing (with the addition of other Locales), I gave it a shot. The US and UK formats are the same: "Apr 27, 2012". I'd expect the UK one to be "27 Apr 2012". The others appear valid, though I'm neither French, Italian, nor Japanese, so I'm not 100% sure. ;-)

Comment: but if u are getting right result then make pass your Locate as `Locale.ITALY` instead of as new Locale("en", "GB").

Comment: As I stated in the question, I've used both `Locale.UK` and `new Locale("en", "GB")` - they are the same, and they both return the wrong format. `Locale.ITALY` is not within the scope of what I'm trying to determine.